# DB2 database open with Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, db2

I want to open Db2 database with Excel macro and fill datas into sheet.

```
Sub db()
Dim conn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim sqls As String
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL;Database=SAMPLE;Hostname=localhost;             
Protocol=TCPIP;Port=50000;Uid=myuid;Pwd=mypw;"
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open sqls, conn
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
End Sub
```

but i got the following error

[image]

I want to open sample table which was created in db2. 
What i should do? thx

Comment: are you using that exact connection string?

Comment: well, in summary, the error message tells you that you need to check your data source name (as it hasn't been found) and specify the default driver.  You will also need to add your username and password in the relevant places, and an sql query

Comment: Shouldn't the provider be `IBMDADB2`?

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this code:**

```
Sub DB2connect()

  'Create the Connection String with Provider and Data Source options

   dim sSQLQry As String
   dim ReturnArray

   dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
   dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
   dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    ws.Activate

    DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName 'Refering the sameworkbook as Data Source

    sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=MyODBC connection name;UID=myuid;PWD=myPass;DBQ=myDatabase" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

    conn.ConnectionTimeout = 30
    conn.Open sconnect

    sSQLSting = " select * from table where ...."

    mrs.Open sSQLSting, conn

    'Import Headers
    For i = 0 To mrs.Fields.Count - 1
       ws.Range("B15").Offset(0, i) = mrs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

    Range("B15").Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset mrs

    mrs.Close
    conn.Close
    Set mrs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing



End Sub
```

**[hier is the code in Github](https://github.com/sulimanfarzat/Excal_vba/blob/master/SQLDatabase_VBA.bas)**